# LWJGL Icon only showing in taskbar

Tags: java, icons, lwjgl

I've setup a method for loading an image into a ByteBuffer and called `Display.setIcon()`, this works... partially. This sets the icon of the taskbar, but leaves the window's icon as the default LWJGL icon. Is there another `Display` method I need to call? Or is this something to do with windows.

Here's the method of loading the icon if needed:

```
public static final ByteBuffer[] getIcon()
{
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("rw_icon.PNG");
    MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(new JPanel());
    tracker.addImage(image, 0);

    try
    {
        tracker.waitForAll();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tracker.removeImage(image);

    BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics2D graphics = bufImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    graphics.dispose();
    image.flush();

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(32*32*4);
    buffer.clear();
    byte[] bufferData = (byte[])bufImage.getRaster().getDataElements(0, 0, 32, 32, null);
    buffer.put(bufferData);
    buffer.rewind();

    return (new ByteBuffer[] {buffer});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

You just need to pass an array of two versions of the icon (16x16, 32x32) to the setIcon(..) method.

It seems like you misunderstood the ByteBuffer[]. You are supposed to pass an array of **different** ByteBuffers. Not just a ByteBuffer array with one element in it. Therefore it would probably be best to create a new method which basically just does what your getIcon() method does, but expects a String as a file path. That way you can easily create the *real* array of icon byte-buffers.

> **public static int setIcon(java.nio.ByteBuffer[] icons)**
>
> Sets one or more icons for the Display. **On Windows you should supply at least one
> 16x16 icon and one 32x32**. Linux (and similar platforms) expect one
> 32x32 icon. Mac OS X should be supplied one 128x128 icon The
> implementation will use the supplied ByteBuffers with image data in
> RGBA (size must be a power of two) and perform any conversions
> nescesarry for the specific platform.
> NOTE: The display will make a
> deep copy of the supplied byte buffer array, for the purpose of
> recreating the icons when you go back and forth fullscreen mode. You
> therefore only need to set the icon once per instance.

[http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setIcon(java.nio.ByteBuffer[])](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setIcon(java.nio.ByteBuffer%5B%5D))

Comment: I guess I skimmed over the documentation a little too fast. I've got it working now perfectly doing exactly as you said. Thanks! Also, that rests my curiosity on why it expects the ByteBuffer(s) as an array.

Comment: @BoltReel Glad it helped! And sometimes you need a 24x24 version too, thats at least what the docs say, not sure about that though ;)